# Как спрятать div?

Tags: javascript

В текстовое поле вводится число, после ввода выводится содержимое блока div, если число изменяется (oninput), то выводится другое содержимое данного блока div, но если число меняется, выводится старое содержимое + новое. Как можно очистить блок div?

Пример: ввели цифру **1** вывелась цитата, изменили **1**, на **2** и вывелась  еще одна цитата, но проблема в том, что старую цитату нужно очистить, ибо выводится 1 и 2-ая цитаты.

Код:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
document.querySelector("input").oninput = function(){
document.querySelector("div").style.display = "block";
if (document.getElementById('number').value==1){
    div=document.getElementById('c1');
    div.style.display='block';
}
if (document.getElementById('number').value==2){
    div=document.getElementById('c2');
    div.style.display='block';
}
if (document.getElementById('number').value==3){
    div=document.getElementById('c3');
    div.style.display='block';
}
if (document.getElementById('number').value==4){
    div=document.getElementById('c4');
    div.style.display='block';
}
if (document.getElementById('number').value==5){
    div=document.getElementById('c5');
    div.style.display='block';
  }
 }
}//]]> 

</script>

</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" value="" name="number" id="number" placeholder="Цифра от 1 до 100" oninput="clear">
<div style="display: none;" id="c1">
    <p>Цитата 1</p>
</div>
<div style="display: none;" id="c2">
    <p>Цитата 2</p>
</div>
<div style="display: none;" id="c3">
    <p>Цитата 3</p>
</div>
<div style="display: none;" id="c4">
    <p>Цитата 4</p>
</div>
<div style="display: none;" id="c5">
    <p>Цитата 5</p>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вашем коде надо не очищать `div`, а прятать. Добавить какой-то признак, чтобы можно было найти сразу все `div` (`id` у формы + `class` у `div`), найти сразу все элементы, и спрятать. И после этого показать один конкретный элемент. Примерно так:

```js
// вставить в самом начале обработчика oninput 
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#sampleform div.quote");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el, i){
   el.style.display = 'none';
});

// if
var div=document.getElementById('c3');
div.style.display='block';
```

```html
<form id="sampleform">
<input type="text" value="" name="number" id="number" placeholder="Цифра от 1 до 100" oninput="clear">
<div style="display: block;" class="quote" id="c1">
    <p>Цитата 1</p>
</div>
<div style="display: block;" class="quote" id="c2">
    <p>Цитата 2</p>
</div>
<div style="display: block;" class="quote" id="c3">
    <p>Цитата 3</p>
</div>
</form>
```

---

очистка любого элемента:

```
el.innerHTML = '';
```

но вообще стоит пересмотреть код, который выводит цитату - поменять его, чтобы он не дописывал текст, а заменял существующий.

Comment: в коде есть условия для каждого числа (if) и выводится определенная цитата. Каким образом можно заменить существующую в таком случае?

Comment: @AlexDemonov приведите в вопросе ту часть кода, которая выводит цитату.

Comment: добавил часть кода

Comment: @AlexDemonov вам нужно не очищать элементы, а прятать их

Comment: если условий много код ведь огромный получится, если каждое прятать.. или можно как-то по другому?

Comment: @AlexDemonov напишите код прятанья один раз, перед первым if. вместо `document.querySelector("div").style.display = "block";`. пусть прячет все div, включая тот, который нужно будет потом показать - он все равно покажется.

Comment: благодарю за подробное объяснение)